# Convert HMAC function from Java to JavaScript

Tags: java, node.js, cryptography, hmac

I am tying to implement an HMAC function in NodeJS using this Java function as a reference:

```
private static String printMacAsBase64(byte[] macKey, String counter) throws Exception {
    // import AES 128 MAC_KEY
    SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(macKey, "AES");

    // create new HMAC object with SHA-256 as the hashing algorithm
    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
    mac.init(signingKey);

    // integer -> string -> bytes -> encrypted bytes
    byte[] counterMac = mac.doFinal(counter.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    // base 64 encoded string
    return DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(counterMac);
}
```

From this I get HMAC of Qze5cHfTOjNqwmSSEOd9nEISOobheV833AncGJLin9Y=

I am getting a different value for the HMAC when passing the same counter and key through the HMAC algorithm in node.  Here is my code to generate the hmac.

```
var decryptedMacKey = 'VJ/V173QE+4CrVvMQ2JqFg==';
var counter = 1;

var hash = crypto
    .createHmac('SHA256',decryptedMacKey)
    .update(new Buffer(counter.toString(),'utf8'),'utf8')
    .digest('base64');
```

When I run this I get a MAC of nW5MKXhnGmgpYwV0qmQtkNBDrCbqQWQSkk02fiQBsGU=

I was unable to find any equivalent to the SecretKeySpec class in javascript so that may be the missing link.

I was also able to generate the same value as my program using this 
https://quickhash.com/ by selecting the algorithm Sha-256 and entering the decrypted mac key and counter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to decode the `decryptedMacKey` from a Base 64 representation:

```
var hash = crypto.createHmac('SHA256', new Buffer(decryptedMacKey, 'base64'))
    .update(new Buffer(counter.toString(),'utf8'),'utf8')
    .digest('base64');
```

gives:

```
'Qze5cHfTOjNqwmSSEOd9nEISOobheV833AncGJLin9Y='
```

Comment: I knew I had to be overlooking something.  I will give it a try.  Thanks!